# Get layout margins from wtihin view

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to set the x and y coordinates of a custom view using `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginTop`. When a layout is inflated, I'm attempting to get the layout parameters during instantiation like so:

```
public class Stick extends View {

    int x, y;

    public Stick(Context context) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams()
        x = layout.leftMargin;
        y = layout.top_Margin;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.test.app.Stick
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
<com.test.app.Stick
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This causes the app to crash immediately with no errors though. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourLayout.getLayoutParams();
        x = layout.leftMargin;
        y = layout.topMargin;
```

Here `yourLayout` is the layout of which you want to get the margins.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException. Is it because I'm trying to get the layout parameters from the view constructor?

Comment: Please see the edited answer.You should use `someLayout.getLayoutParams()`.